# I turned my iMac on, but I only see a grey blinking question mark folder

Tags: macos, hard-drive, imac, startup

I bought a 2011 21.5" iMac in a garage sale.

1. I pressed <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. Once I'm in the macOS Utility folder, I don't see the Macintosh HD.
2. Now, I went back to macOS Utility and tried to re-install macOS High Sierra  . Everything was going fine until the iMac asked me **Please Select the Drive**, but I  don't see any Internal Hard Drive in the dialogue box?

Comment: There's [almost 200 posts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=mac+question+mark) about seeing the question mark on this site.  Have you tried any of the solutions already provided?  If so, please [edit] your question to identify which ones and any errors you received.

Comment: I think you should try installing macOS on an external drive then boot into your iMac after which you can open disk utility to check if your main internal hard drive is still intact, it might be corrupted!