# Is my hard drive missing if a iMac 2011 purchased at a garage sale boots up with a flashing grey question mark?

Tags: mac

I bought a iMac 2011 at a garage sale. But when I boot it up, I get a flashing grey question mark. Disk utility can't find Macintosh HD. Probably owner deleted files and HD? Do I need to install SSD drive to reinstall Sierra?

Comment: Duplicate question : https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/342410/237687

Answer (score 3):

Try this: Press and hold <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> at startup and use Internet recovery mode.